# TikZ PGF - Minus sign being interpreted as a unit of measure

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros, arguments, pgfmathparse

I'm trying to write a macro that draws a number line given a number of tick marks to use. However, there are a couple of spots in the code where I try to do arithmetic using the argument of the command, specifically `1/(#1-1+3)` and `#1-1`, that don't seem to want to work. I get an error message saying the following:

```
Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
<to be read again> 
                   -
l.96 \numline{5}
```

It seems to be treating the minus sign `-` as a unit of measure, but I'm not sure how that could happen. My full code follow below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\numline}[1]{
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\spacing}{1/(#1-1+3)}%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=\textwidth/1cm]
    \draw[latex-latex,thick] (0,0) -- (1,0);
    \foreach \i in {0,...,#1-1}
        \draw[shift={(1.5*\spacing+\i,0)},color=black,thick] (0pt,5/6pt) -- (0pt,-5/6pt);
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\numline{5}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SE! Ti*k*Z is smart, but not *that* smart. TikZ don't perform math operations inside the `\foreach` expressions but you need to help Ti*k*Z a bit. That's why I added `\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\imax}{#1-1}` and used `\imax` in the loop.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\numline}[1]{
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\spacing}{1/(#1-1+3)}%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=\textwidth/1cm]
    \draw[latex-latex,thick] (0,0) -- (1,0);
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\imax}{#1-1}
    \foreach \i in {0,...,\imax}
        \draw[shift={(1.5*\spacing+\i,0)},color=black,thick] (0pt,5/6pt) -- (0pt,-5/6pt);
    \end{tikzpicture}
}
\numline{5}
\end{document}
```

Alternatively you can force to perform the integer arithmetic via `\numexpr`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,calc}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\numline}[1]{
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\spacing}{1/(#1-1+3)}%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=\textwidth/1cm]
    \draw[latex-latex,thick] (0,0) -- (1,0);
    \foreach \i in {0,...,\numexpr#1-1\relax}
        \draw[shift={(1.5*\spacing+\i,0)},color=black,thick] (0pt,5/6pt) -- (0pt,-5/6pt);
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\numline{5}

\end{document}
```

My suspicion is that you may want something like this, though.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\numline}[1]{
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\spacing}{1/(#1-1+3)}%
    \typeout{\spacing}
\centerline{\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=\textwidth/1cm]
    \draw[latex-latex,thick] (0,0) -- (1,0);
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\imax}{#1-1}
    \foreach \i in {0,...,\imax}
        \draw[thick] 
        ({(1.5+\i)*\spacing},5/6pt) -- ({(1.5+\i)*\spacing},-5/6pt);
    \end{tikzpicture}}
}
\begin{document}
\numline{5}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You could even use relative coordinates for the second coordinate pair (`++(0,-10/6pt)`). Also note that `5/6pt` only works as expected because the `5` is also interpreted as `5pt` (it's the default unit), but when you try `5/6mm` it will be interpreted as `5pt/6mm` which is approximately `0.29mm`.

Comment: Thank you; the third solution is indeed exactly what I was looking for! I notice now that I didn't apply the `\spacing` factor to everything in the original code. What was the problem with using the `shift` attribute in the `\draw` command?

Comment: @ArrowM There is no real problem but I personally find the other syntax more intuitive.